# php regex for string containing a "." and "-"

Tags: php, regex, string

Hay all, i need help making a regex. The string must contain a "-" and must not contain a ".".

Can someone help me please.

Comment: That's a bit vague... Can you be a bit more specific about the format you expect the strings to be in?

Comment: Thats the format. the string must contain a '-' and must not contain a '.'

Comment: OK - no need for a regex then: see Franz's and ghostdog74's answers.

Comment: @dotty: Note that *must contain a `-`* is ambiguous: It can be interpreted as *must contain exactly one `-`* or *must contain at least one `-`*.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You don't need a regex for that:

```
if (strpos($string, '-') !== false && strpos($string, '.') === false)
    //do what you want...
```

Comment: strpos() is more efficient than regex matches, especially in cases like this. This is the perfect answer. +1

Comment: strpos has to scan the string twice, a good regexp only once!

Comment: @reto: True. Would have to run a benchmark to havee the "real" comparison. But in a simple case like this it probably does not matter, I think... Do you agree?

Comment: Franz: I dont really like the outcome of that particular regexp (it looks a bit akward), but for the 99 other cases a regexp is much more cleaner and explicit. And this strpos-0-might-be-false-lets-use-===-akwardness only makes it worse.

So for me the regexp is the simpler solution, but this is a matter of taste.. your opinion might differ.

Comment: Yeah, I see your point. I agree regexes are often cleaner, but sometimes they are harder to read - especially if you're not too experienced with them. Then again: you're right, strpos() isn't the most easy one to read, either ;)

Comment: +1 for not answering the question by the book, but instead giving a better answer

Answer (score 3):

Don't know about php, but this should do it:

```
^[^.]*-[^.]*$
```

Comment: Don't forget the anchors! `^` and `$`

Comment: @Gumbo: Sharp eyes, as always. ;-)

Comment: Can you explain why it does make it more performant? I'm not that good with regexes... ;)

Comment: @Franz: Since the `*` quantifier is greedy, the preceeding expression `[^.]` would consume as much as it can before backtracking will be used to match the rest of the expression. So if the test string is `foo-bar`, `[^.]*` will first match the whole string, then step back until `[^.]*-` matches `foo-` and then match the rest so that the whole expression matches. With `[^.-]*` the expression will always just match the `foo` without backtracking.

Comment: @Gumbo - thanks for that. The though did cross my mind, but I wasn't sure it's necessary. I'll read. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

no need regex for this, one method is to use strpos

```
strpos($mystr,"-" ) !== FALSE && strpos($mystr,"." ) === FALSE
```